# How L2 switching and L3 routing work in Software Defined Network (SDN)?

Tags: networking, routing, subnet

In traditional networking, let say host1,host2 are both connected to switch1 and switch2 respectively, in the different subnet and both switch connect to a router. If host1 want to sent an IP packet to host2, in this case host2 is located in different subnet so switch1 will forward this packet to default gateway (Router). After Router received the IP packet, it will do several route function so that the host1 and host2 finally can communicate.

I would like to ask you the same scenario but using SDN? How host1 and host2 in different subnet communicate using SDN network?

Thanks you very much, appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific details depend a lot on the implementation, but in general terms **it would be the same**, with the only difference that the switches and routers are software. Usually the switch would reside on the hypervisor's host (often called vmswitch) and the router might be either a set of policies on the host or just another VM. As these network functions (switching, routing) are virtualized, this part of SDN might be referred to as NFV (Network Function Virtualization).

However, this traffic still needs to travel in the physical datacenter and host1 and host2 might be residing on different and physically separated hypervisors (regardless if host1 and host2 "think" they are in the same subnet). All traffic from the software defined network will be encapsulated (most implementations use either VXLAN or GRE for encapsulation) and routed accordingly to the datacenter's physical networking.

You could think about it in a similar way to how a VPN works. Many devices might join a VPN and they can talk to each other on that VPN network as if they were in the same LAN, however their traffic is really encapsulated (+ encrypted) and traveling through Internet.

I would recommend you to dig deeper by learning how VXLAN or NVGRE work. It would clarify a lot of concepts for you.

Answer (score 0):

on routing process (without NAT) there is some replacement MAC address process. On SDN wich work on flow base can modify flow and also can modify MAC address of packet. There is some different work in traditional and SDN. I suggest you use ryu or pox to inspect process packet on SDN. There is many starterkit, or maybe you can use https://github.com/dektiram/SDNColdBrew for starterkit.